# Is it possible - and advisable - to remove the Email Experience Manager, Forms and Marketing Automation from a 9.1 setup?

Tags: solution-architecture

I'm upgrading to Sitecore 9.1.

My solution will not need to use the EXM, Forms or MA.

Can I get rid of them, together with their associated database? How can I go about doing this, and is it a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Is it possible?

Sure, anything is possible.  The question you need to ask is how much removal of configurations do you want to deal with, and possible break the ability to upgrade in the future?

### Is it advisable?

That's pretty opinionated, which might result in the closure of this question. However, before it's closed, let me offer this professinal's opinion. ***No. (Mostly)***

### Reasoning

#### Email Experience Manager

There's an off setting here for EXM.  Defining the `exm:enabled` setting to False or No, EXM will be disabled and the icon removed.  This does allow you to forgo installing the Database, and that setting automatically deactivates the comfiguration files. This is where the ***Mostly*** comes in.

#### Forms

Forms is an intregal part of Sitecore XP. It has no off switch and to turn it off requires removal of the ExperienceForms configs as well as the Core Database items.  Sure, you can remove all of this, but it will require additional effort for future upgrades, and introduces risk.  If you really don't want to use it, your best bet is probably to just remove the Launchpad Icon for forms and call it a day.

#### Marketing Automation

This is the biggie. It has hooks into all functions of Sitecore.  Additionally it represents one third of the functionality of xConnect.  Removing this would probably require some heavy testing and troubleshooting and probably breaks a lot of the upgrade paths.  That, said, it's do able if you want the pain.

### In Summary

I don't think the effort invovled is worth the minimal infrastructure savings.  Your milage may vary.